# Eevee transparency together with reflections

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, effects

I'm testing out the capabilities of the eevee render engine. I have a cube object with a mix shader of a principled bsdf and a transparent bsdf. The idea is to move a wave texture across the object and use that as a factor in the mix shader to have lines of transparent and solids. The solid material has metallic=1 and clearcoat=1 and roughness=0, which should give it a highly reflective surface.

In eevee to achieve the transparency, the screen space reflections (ssr) + refraction in the render properties is turned on, as well as per object settings ssr + blend/shadow modes=alpha blend. But, reflections are best handled as reflection planes with ssr turned off. Additionally, the eevee refraction doesn't take into account the waves moving in the back faces, so it looks like a cube with with only the viewer faces being affected. Is this a fundamental limitation?

Comment: do you mean like this? https://youtu.be/86C7cj--zjc. if not, please add some screenshots to make it more clear. thanks.

Comment: yes that's right. Is that using eevee?

Comment: yes it is...i will post it as answer...give me 2 mins ;)

Comment: Reflection light probes are *a* good way to get high quality reflections, depending on the mesh (cube maps are another, for different kinds of meshes) but they actually require SSR enabled-- they don't work otherwise.  Refraction + backface transparency, yes, there's nothing you can do about that, that one is a fundamental limitation of Eevee (of any rasterizer, really, it's not like it's Eevee's fault.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the node tree:

[image]

It is just a basic setup with wave texture to do the difference between the shiny material and the transparent. Because me personally i like the "sharp" edge instead of easing so i used the greater than node to realize this. Without it, it looks pretty blurry. By the way: by playing with the threshold you can increase/decrease the bands size. And then the mix shader, which decides whether the transparent or the shiny material should be shown.

**Important**: material settings -> blend mode like this:

[image]

As a little *bonus* a added a frame node, which animates the offset, because i just ***love*** animations ;)

result:

[image]

animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86C7cj--zjc

blend file:

[image]

Comment: Great! That really clears up how to set those nodes up. On my part, i was using alpha blend instead of alpha hashed. Additionally, the ssr should be turned on for realistic reflections. I had it off because purely reflected objects seemed clearest without ssr on.